# Software for controling laser cutter/engraving machine, or alternative to LaserGRBL

Tags: linux, software-rec

I recently bought a laser cutter/engraver machine, an Ortur Laser Master II. I am now looking for software to control it.

Usually, people use it with Windows and the LaserGRBL open-source software. For GNU/Linux, it is advised to use a commercial software called Lightburn, which is free for a 30-days trial.

I am looking for an open-source alternative for Linux.

Maybe some of you are actually working with this machine and use on open-source alternative to control the Ortur, so I ask.

My system : Void Linux, 5.8.14_1 GNU/Linux kernel.

Comment: The LaserGRBL GitHub repository has [a closed issue](https://github.com/arkypita/LaserGRBL/issues/5) with a long thread about getting it to run on Linux. It seems as if they gave up on it, but there is [one entry](https://github.com/arkypita/LaserGRBL/issues/5#issuecomment-439732678) there pointing to something called [cncjs](https://github.com/cncjs/cncjs) as an alternative.  The `cncjs` documentation may provide further interesting resources.  Not an answer since I know nothing about these things.

Comment: I use lasergrbl on Linux to control my ortur lm2 and it works fine. I have Windowsfx but it should work on other distributions. I have the latest version of wine and the port is 33

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use [LinuxCNC](http://linuxcnc.org/). It's open source

LinuxCNC controls CNC machines. It can drive milling machines, lathes, 3D printers, laser cutters, plasma cutters, robot arms, hexapods, and more.

- Runs under Linux (optionally with realtime extensions).
- Simple installation on Debian and Ubuntu, or via our Live/Install DVD/USB images.
- Accepts G-code input, drives CNC machines in response.
- Active user community.
- Several different GUIs available.
- Compatible with many popular machine control hardware interfaces.
- Supports rigid tapping, cutter compensation, and many other advanced control features.
- [Full source code available](https://github.com/LinuxCNC/linuxcnc) under the terms of the [GNU GPLv2 (General Public License version 2)](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html).

---

[Follow Installation Here](http://linuxcnc.org/docs/2.8/html/getting-started/getting-linuxcnc.html) and Read [Documentation for Current Release LinuxCNC version 2.8](http://linuxcnc.org/docs/2.8/html/):